# Find an equation tangent to the curve at the point corresponding to the given value of the parameter

Tags: calculus, parametric

$x = 1 +4t -t^2$,   $y = 2 - t^3$,  at $t=1$

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ $= \frac{-3}{2}$ at t = 1.

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the tangent is just:

$$y- y(1) = y'(1) (x - 1)$$

where $y'(1)$ is $dy/dx$ at $1$. We get:

$$y = -\frac32 x + 7$$

Another way to solve the problem: let $f(t)= (1+4t - t^2, 2 - t^3)$. We have $f'(1) = (2,-3)$ is a direction vector of the tangent line $T$, and $T$ passes through $f(1) = (4,1)$, so a parameterization of $T$ is given by:

$$\begin{cases} x = 2t + 4 \\ y = -3t + 1 \end{cases}$$

Comment: Okay thank you. Where did you derive that equation from?

Comment: @K.Gibson See below, I give you the derivation

Comment: @K.Gibson one way to arrive at it is by using the method I added in the edit

Comment: @AhmedHussein I also think it should have y intercept of 7

Comment: @qbert you are right

Comment: @AhmedHussein I always make those kinds of silly mistakes :P I think you caught me on one yesterday

Comment: @qbert everybody does :)

Comment: Thank you both @AhmedHussein I am a little confused to your second approach but I think that is because that is covered in later chapters.Are  you are talking about the gradient vector in the direction of $f(t)$?

Comment: $f(t)$ is a curve, not a scalar valued function of multiple arguments, and as such does not have a gradient. A gradient is defined for functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, n>1. Ahmed gave you a parametric equation of a line with given slope passing through the given point

Answer (score 1):

So you have the slope of your line, and a point it goes through. Using 
$$
y-y_0=m(x-x_0)
$$
And inputting 
$$
(x_0,y_0)=(1+4-1,2-1)=(4,1), m=-3/2
$$
You find the equation
$$
y-1=-\frac{3}{2}(x-4)=3*2-\frac{3}{2}x=6-\frac{3}{2}x\Rightarrow y=7-\frac{3}{2}x
$$

Comment: @K.Gibson No problem, good luck!